# You know me best X You know me better

Tags: comparatives, best-most

What's the difference between "best" and "better" in these sentences:

"You know me **BEST** as Ash Ketchum on Pokemon"

"If you want to know me **BETTER** professionally, ask me for my Curriculum Vitæ."

For me, I always used "better" in this context, why and when should I use "know me best"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is the same as it normally is between *better* and *best.*

> If you want to know me better (than you do now)...
>
> You know me best as A (A is the one of my various names which is the most widely known).

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence has no clear comparison like know me better as Ash than as anything else, or, like in the second sentence, know me better than you know me now, so the use of *better* can be confusing. Also, it still implies *better than anything else*, which means *best*.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Oh, I see, I think it was confusing to me since my native language has only one word for "best" or "better", in this case, there's only one context also. In my language, for the first sentence, I would never think of it as "best", but "better".